# How to add a extra column in dataframe with a checking condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the issue to break the dataframe into two lines.
I have the following two dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Item':['A','B','C'],'Value':[4,3,7]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Item':['A','B','C'],'Value':[4,3,2]})

df1:
    Item    Value
0      A        4
1      B        3
2      C        7

df2:
    Item    Value
0      A        4
1      B        3
2      C        2
```

I would like to set a limit for the value, let say limit = 10

```
limit = 10
```

After that I want to add a extra column and check if the items is within the limit
if not, I want to break it into two line and show the following result:
However, if it is within limit, I want to add an extra line to show there are how many amount left for the limit:

```
df1:
    Item    Value   within_limit
0      A        4            Yes
1      B        3            Yes
2      C        3            Yes
3      C        4             No

df2:
    Item    Value   within_limit
0      A        4            Yes
1      B        3            Yes
2      C        2            Yes
3    Nan        1          Extra
```

How can I get the above result?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: @AMC I dont exactly know how to break the item in two lines. Is there any function can do this?

Comment: What happens if you have, in `df1` another row with `Item D Value 2`?

Comment: @QuangHoang item d will append on result of df1 as df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Item':['A','B','C','C','D'],'Value':[4,3,3,3,2],'within_limit':['Yes','Yes','Yes','No','No']})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your function, this assumes that the index is range index:

```
def check_limit(df, limit):
    s = df['Value'].cumsum()
    df['within_limit'] = np.where(s.le(limit), 'Yes', 'No')

    # Nothing off limit
    if s.iloc[-1] < limit:
        return df.append(pd.Series([np.nan, limit-s.iloc[-1],'Extra'], 
                                  index=df.columns,
                                  name=len(df))
                      )

    # all sum even to limit
    if s.iloc[-1] == limit: return df

    # find where the limit is exceeded
    idx = s.gt(limit).idxmax()
    # exceed limit
    exceed_limit = s.loc[idx] - limit

    new_df = df.loc[[idx,idx]].copy()
    new_df['Value'] = [df.loc[idx,'Value'] - exceed_limit, exceed_limit]
    new_df['within_limit'] = ['Yes','No']

    return pd.concat((df.drop(idx), new_df)).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

# test data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Item':['A','B','C', 'D'],'Value':[4,3,7,2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Item':['A','B','C'],'Value':[4,3,2]})
```

Output:

```
# check_limit(df1, 10)
  Item  Value within_limit
0    A      4          Yes
1    B      3          Yes
2    C      3          Yes
3    C      4           No
4    D      2           No

# check_limit(df2, 10)
  Item  Value within_limit
0    A      4          Yes
1    B      3          Yes
2    C      2          Yes
3  NaN      1        Extra
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I want. Thank you for your kindly help.